# How to delete the files present in a directory

Tags: shell, unix

I have a folder in my directory called `input_files` which contains the list of input files. I am trying to delete the contents of this folder using the below command but getting I'm getting an error.

```
find /u/users/kisri1/scripts/design_matrix/input_files*  -type f -delete
```

Error:

```
/u/users/kisri1/scripts/design_matrix/input_files: Is a directory
```

Please help to solve this thing. I want to write a shell script which can access the folder and delete the files.

Comment: try .../input_files/*

Answer (score 0):

`rm` is perfect in your case.

`rm -rf /u/users/kisri1/scripts/design_matrix/input_files/*` would do the trick and delete all files in your `input_files` directory without discrimination.

Answer (score 0):

use the lines:

```
cd /u/users/kisri1/scripts/design_matrix/input_files
rm *
```

this will delete all files in the directory